# Unknown column in 'where clause' while column exists MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a weird problem when trying to run an SQL query in phpmyadmin.
my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Dozen 
WHERE Dozen.registered = '1' 
AND Dozen.DoosID = Klant_Doos.DoosID 
AND Klant_Doos.KlantID = '1'
```

When running it in phpmyadmin on the right database with column Klant_Doos existing it returns the following error.

## 1054 - Unknown column 'Klant_Doos.DoosID' in 'where clause'

I've been doing some testing and this problem only seems to appear when i use

```
Table.Column = OtherTable.OtherColumn
```

If I use

```
Table.Column = 'Value'
```

it return results just fine.

Is it my syntax or did I just discover a bug in phpmyadmin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dozen and Klant_Doos are two separate tables. You need to use Join.

Comment: you are selecting data from Dozen and in where condition refering a field in Klant_Doos table and this is the reason, you need to use JOIN between the tables.

Comment: You forgot to join the table klant_doos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a table reference in your `from` clause.  Is this what you are trying to do?

```
SELECT *
FROM Dozen JOIN
     Klant_Doos
     ON Dozen.DoosID = Klant_Doos.DoosID 
WHERE Dozen.registered = '1' AND
      Klant_Doos.KlantID = '1';
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the problem. Just needed to add "AND" between "WHERE Dozen.registered = '1'" and "Klant_Doos.KlantID = '1'"; for the syntax to be right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved by specifying `Klant_Doos` table in the `SELECT` clause as well:

```
SELECT * FROM Dozen, Klant_Doos 
WHERE Dozen.registered = '1' 
AND Dozen.DoosID = Klant_Doos.DoosID 
AND Klant_Doos.KlantID = '1'
```

Yet, the more common (and explicit) way to write such a query is to perform a `JOIN`.

Comment: I was reading the "SQL in 10 minutes" book, and they have some solutions like this in the subqueries section. The code only works if FROM includes both tables for MySQL. Thanks!